# diff unexpectedly shows all lines have been modified - but they haven't

Tags: mercurial

I made one little change (removed some trailing whitespaces) then

I ran hg diff [File Name], and it says all lines are modified.

I had this problem before then it was fixed somehow then it's back again.

I didn't upgrade mercurial or anything.

Did anyone experience something like this and managed to figure out a way to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you changed `\n` to `\r\n` on vice versa?

Comment: Seems like that was the problem... Thanks!